# Does the range of "short" differ between machines?

Tags: c

Could anyone tell me if the range of short in C differs on different machines. For example, if a short is 2 bytes, and in a 1's complement machine the range of short will be `-32767 ~ 32767` and in a 2's complement machine the range will be `-32768 ~ 32767`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And if a short was 4 bytes, the range would be -2147483648 to 2147483647 or so. That actually _could_ happen.

Comment: Let us know when you find one of those 1's complement machines.

Comment: @GregHewgill Do you mean there is no 1's complement machine?

Comment: @John: You might find one in a museum, but that's about it.

Comment: @John For all practical purposes, 2's complement "won". It would be interesting to know what machines in production -- however legacy -- work on 1's complement. I know that some UNIVAC did... but really? :)

Comment: Does a unicorn have ticklish armpits?

Comment: @pst: There's really no such thing as a *machine working on ones complement*. Ultimately a machine just works on binary values with no sign interpretation, which via modular arithmetic, **is** twos complement. The issue is that some machines have signed-comparison (and signed mul/div instructions..?!) that interpret values as ones complement. But if you (or your compiler) just treat all arithmetic as unsigned when writing/generating asm, and roll your own signed comparisons (easy), any machine can be twos complement. A ones complement C impl. is nothing but a bad implementation choice.

Comment: @R..: Actually the hardware *can* be different. The [Ones' complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones'_complement) article on Wikipedia is a fascinating bit of history. Bottom line, the ALU can be wired differently to perform different kinds of arithmetic. Some machines even had logic between the CPU and memory that changed the representation back and forth between sign-magnitude. The concept is so foreign today because everything we work with is twos' complement.

Comment: @Greg: My point was that there's always a way to perform unsigned arithmetic, and if you just use that for both your signed and unsigned arithmetic, you get twos complement for free, and you can ignore whatever useless logic was thrown in for ones complement or sign/magnitude.

Comment: @R..: it's really a question of the performance of division, isn't it? If the hardware has 1s' complement division ops with actual circuits behind them, then your emulated 2's complement signed division is going to be comparatively slow. The same is true for your emulated 2's complement subtraction, but to a lesser degree. If making `int` 1s' complement in C is a "poor implementation choice" on the basis that programmers are used to 2's complement and tend to write non-portable code, then buying that machine in the first place was an even worse hardware choice by the user.

Comment: So either way we can reasonably say, "I don't care, I'm going to write non-portable code that assumes 2's complement", provided we document that people who make such poor choices can't run our code. But if someone's fool enough to build a 1s' complement machine, I don't see why the person who writes the C implementation for that machine should have to cater to me by emulating 2's complement. They might want to, but if they choose instead to not run my code, that's also a reasonable choice.

Comment: @Steve: Consider the C99 `intX_t` types that are requires to be twos complement if they exist. A program requiring them to be present (and testing for it) is a lot more reasonable than requiring `int` to be twos complement, but the easiest way for a compiler to provide them is to use twos complement to begin with. And as long as there's a dedicated unsigned `SUB` opcode, no emulation is needed for subtraction. With the new C99 rules for division with negative operands, it may already be necessary to emulate all divisions as a positive division followed by sign fixup, too...

Comment: @R..: that's true, it's kind of weird that C99 banned signed division from rounding negative numbers away from zero, but didn't ban 1s' complement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the range and size of type `short` differ on different machines.  It can even differ across different implementations on the same machine.

The most common representation is 16 bits, two's-complement, with no padding bits or trap representations, for a range of -32768 to +32767.

The C standard requires `short` to cover *at least* a range of -32767 to +32767, but it can be bigger.

I've worked on systems where `short` is 32 bits (Cray T3E) or even 64 bits (Cray T90).

If at all possible, you should write code that doesn't assume a particular range or size for `short`, or for any of the other predefined types.  Use `SHRT_MIN` and `SHRT_MAX`, defined in `<limits.h>`, if you need the bounds, and use `sizeof (short)`, (or better, `sizeof obj` where `obj` is an object of type `short`) if you need the size.

If you need a type that's *exactly* 16 bits, use `int16_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>`.  (Those headers were added in the 1999 version of the C standard, but most compilers should support them.)

In response to your comment asking about overflow:

Questions of overflow get a bit tricky when you're talking about type `short`.  Integer literals like `32767` are never of type `short`; they're always of type `int` or something even bigger.  And operands of arithmetic operators have the "usual arithmetic conversions" applied to them first; `short` operands are quietly promoted to `int`.

**In C, there is no `+` operator for type `short`**.

So consider this:

```
short x = 32767;
x = x + 1;
```

In the expression `x + 1`, the operand `x` is promoted from `short` to `int` (and `1` is already of type `int`).  That yields a result of type `int`, which will be `32768` if `int` is wide enough to store that value.  (If it isn't, the overflow causes undefined behavior, but we'll ignore that.)  Then the `int` value `32768` is *converted* from `int` to `short` before being stored in `x`.

If `SHRT_MAX > 32767`, there's no problem; the conversion yields the expected value of `32768`, which is stored in `x`.

But if `SHRT_MAX == 32767` (which is the most common case), then the conversion of the `int` value `32768` to `short` *yields an implementation-defined value* (or raises an implementation-defined signal), as described in [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section 6.3.1.3.

Most commonly, the actual result is `-32768`, which is representable as a `short` if the system uses two's-complement (which almost all systems do).  But strictly speaking, the code is not portable, and it *could* store some other arbitrary result in `x`, or even terminate your program if the implementation decides to raise a signal (I don't know of any that do that).

Comment: Thank you. So the values for an overflow would be different depends on the machine? For example, 32767 + 1 = -32767 or 32768 and C won't take care of it.

Comment: @John: Basically, yes, but it's more complex than that.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's permitted to, by the same language in the standard that applies to all integer types (integer representation is 6.2.6.2 in both C99 and C11).